# Why "as" keyword with class doesn't works unless in an array?

Tags: c#, casting

If I try to use "as" keyword to generate a null value it gives me runtime error.

```
Base x = new AClass() as Base;
```

But the error does not occur if I make an array and implement it. It gives me the null value as expected.

```
        I1[] array = new I1[1];
        array[0] = new AClass();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            //Works
            Base x = array[0] as Base;
```

Why is that happening? array[0] = new AClass(). Whats wrong with not having an array?

Comment: why not do: Base x = null?

Comment: What is the runtime error? And is `AClass` a direct or indirect subclass of `Base`? And what are you _actually_ trying to achieve (since just assigning `null` directly apparently isn't an option)?

Comment: You're going to have to give more detail. I can't replicate your results. If `AClass` inherits from `Base` everything works fine and I don't get a runtime error. If `AClass` doesn't inherit from `Base` I get a compiler error.

Comment: "A runtime error", you should post the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant compiler error which is:

> Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApplication1.AClass' to
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Base' via a reference conversion, boxing
>   conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type
>   conversion

This happens when `AClass` doesn't inherit from `Base`.
Now you might think why having interface converting to `Base` also doesn't fail. That's because there is a possibility that some subclass of `Base` implements `I1` which would be valid conversion.
Also the variable being array has no bearing on why this works or fails, as show in my code below.

I used this code

```
        interface I1 { }
        class AClass : I1 { }
        class Base { }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            I1 myAClass = new AClass();
            Base x = myAClass as Base;
        }
```